# Flat website converted to RoR site

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a website that is currently built using only HTML/CSS and a little JavaScript here and there. I'm looking to now take this existing website and turn it into a rails apps. I have several directories (Home, About, Projects, etc) each with their own index.html and css/js files.

I'm now learning RoR and want to turn this into a Rails app. Please help with this process.

Comment: If it is a static HTML/CSS website, why would you turn it into a rails app?

Comment: Planning on adding additional features in the future. Also, I currently have a few forms (contact, signup for product launch) that I need to capture the data

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend reading some books on rails: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4, http://www.manning.com/bigg2/

Comment: I do have some exerience with rails but only building an app from scratch. Is there any easier way that I'm not thinking of to bring in a static site?

Comment: Sure, I like to help other people. What is your question?

Comment: @spickermann I have a static website containing our company's information (home page,about page, contact page, and few other pages). As of right now it's all HTML/CSS/JS but we want to turn it into a rails application. As of right now, the only reason we are doing that is to capture data from one form (contact us form) but we will be building out other features in the future...I'm confused on how to bring in all our directories into the rails app?

Comment: You can put everything that should not be handled by Rails (static pages, images) into the `/public` folder in your app. Than your page should be browsable again without any Rails code written. After that start to extract a layout file.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. I completely forgot about the public folder and adding static pages. So is it possible to drag all my directories over from my static site into the public folder? How do you suggest starting to extract a layout file? This is where I'm getting lost.

Comment: Start a pages_controller and try to rebuild one specific page in Rails. Then rebuild another page and extract common pages (header, footer) into a layout file. Step by step. But stackoverflow comments are a bad place to explain that process. Try do do it yourself first and ask new question here about specific problems on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
#app/models/page.rb
Class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    #schema ->
       id
       title
       content
       created_at
       updated_at

    scope :not, ->(title) { where('pages.title != ?', title)  } 
end

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
Class Pages < ApplicationController

    def show
        @page = Page.find_by title: params[:title]
    end

end

#app/views/pages/show.html.haml
= @page.content

#config/routes.rb
root to: "pages#show", title: "home"

begin  
  for page in Page.all.not("home")
     get "#{page.title}" => "pages#show", title: page.title
  end
rescue
end
```

This allows you to store all your pages in a `Page` model (db), and will create routes for each of them. Very basic, but is precisely what you need

Comment: Isn't taking all the directories and dragging them into the public folder the same thing? I was told to do that and when I fired up the server it seems like all routes are still working properly?

Comment: That's like having a Ferrari with a VW engine inside - completely beyond the point. Rails is meant to work as a full stack framework - anything less is really bad. If you really want to create a Rails app, I'd do it properly otherwise you'll be better with HTML or Wordpress

Comment: this isn't going to bring over the layout for each file?

Comment: Your app should have its layouts in the views/layouts folder

Comment: really struggling with this. At this point, I'm just trying to get the static form to save to the database which needs to be completed in the next hour. any help would be greatly appreciated to get by